# Covering number of the conditional distribution function

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, st.statistics, probability-distributions, packing-and-covering

Suppose $Y$ is a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and we want to find the covering number
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{F} = \big\{ F_{Y|W} (y | W) : y \in \mathbb{R}^d \big\}
\end{equation*}
where $W$ is another random variable in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $F_{Y|W} (y | W)$ is the conditional distribution function. Denote $P_{Y, W}$ is the law of $(Y, W)$, what we want to find is the covering number $N(\epsilon, \mathcal{F}, L_2(P_{Y, W}))$.

At the first glimpse, this question is quite simple, since if we treat $W$ as a determined number, then
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{F} = \overline{\operatorname{conv}}(\mathcal{G}),
\end{equation*}
where $\mathcal{G} := \big\{ 1(Y \leq y) : y \in \mathbb{R}^d \big\}$ with $N(\epsilon, \mathcal{G}, L_2(P_{Y})) \lesssim \epsilon^{- 2d}$ (This is because $F_{Y|W} (y | W) : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow [0, 1]$ is a distribution function). Then by the result for convex hulls, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \log N \big( \epsilon, \mathcal{F}, L_2 (P_Y)\big) \lesssim \epsilon^{-2 d/ (d + 1)}.
\end{equation*}

However, I think the randomness of $W$ complex this problem: what we want is $N(\epsilon, \mathcal{F}, L_2(P_{Y, W}))$ rather than $N ( \epsilon, \mathcal{F}, L_2 (P_Y))$. And I try to find some articles about this, but it is proved to be futile.

So can anyone help me with this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this paper and references therein for the covering numbers for CDF's of signed measures: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.09244.

Comment: Also, your function space is a bit weird. Are you treating $W \mapsto F_{Y|W}(y|X)$ as an element of your space and then varying over $y$? In this case, you need a different approach.

Comment: $F_{Y|W}$ is the same for all functions in your space. So your convex hull argument is not correct (or at least does not allow you to handle the $W$ randomness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different approach. Each function in your function space can be written as
$$F_{Y|W}(y|W) = \int 1(s \leq y) P(Y = ds|W)$$
for some $y$. Thus,
$$\|F_{Y|W}(y_2|W) - F_{Y|W}(y_1|W)\|_{L^1} = E_{P_W}|F_{Y|W}(y_2|W) - F_{Y|W}(y_1|W)| \leq E_{P_W}\int 1(y_1 \leq s \leq y_2) P(Y = ds|W) \lessapprox \|1(Y \leq y_2) - 1(Y \leq y_1)\|_{L^1}.$$
A similar argument probably works for $L^2$.
In particular, your function space is obtained by a Lipschitz transformation applied to the function space
$$\mathcal{F}_{ind} = \{s \mapsto 1(s\leq y): y \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
So your covering number is essentially that of $\mathcal{F}_{ind} $.

Comment: Thanks very much!